# Error is sample XML - don't see the issue?

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest

I've been trying to run the sample code from this website : http://www.apriorit.com/our-company/dev-blog/227-handle-sms-on-android

I downloaded the code, posted it into eclipse and I am getting errors with the android manifest.

This is where I'm getting the errors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.secure.sms"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="0.1" >
```

It's two errors, right after each other saying " Content is not allowed in prolog"

Any ideas what is wrong with these lines?

Here is the full manifest just in case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.secure.sms"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="0.1" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
 -
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
 -
        <activity
            android:name=".SecureMessagesActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
 -
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
 -
        <receiver
            android:name=".SmsReceiver"
            android:exported="true" >
 -
            <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: What are those hyphens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have copy pasted the code which is resulted in the addition of extra hyphens which violate the xml syntax. That is why you get that error `Content is not allowed in prolog` . Removing the hyphens should solve your problem. BTW I would suggest you download the source code and import that directly to eclipse instead of copy pasting each code snippet by this way `File--> New--> Android Project From existing code --> browsing the downloaded source file.`

Comment: Thank you so much for getting back to me!  I don't see File--> New--> Android Project From existing code, I can' only go to File--> New--> Android Project.  Is there another way to import the existing code?  I already have it saved in my workspace

Comment: Go to New --> others --> there you would be able to find.